# discord python problem with message filtering: attachments and message lenght

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to make a bot to filter the messages, so users who doesnt have role specified in this [allowed_role_ids] can only send attachments with no text in message

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
intents.message_content = True  

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  guild_id = 1127616941348114533  
  channel_id = 1127616941348114536  
  message_content = "bot works!"  

  guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)

  if guild is not None:
    channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)  

    if channel is not None:
      await channel.send(message_content)
      print("message was send")
    else:
      print("didnt find channel with this ID.")
  else:
    print("didnt find server with this ID.")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    allowed_channel_ids = [1127616941348114536]
    allowed_role_ids = [1127623171852472350, 1127624324933750886]  
    attachment = message.attachments

    if message.channel.id in allowed_channel_ids:
      if not any(role.id in allowed_role_ids for role in message.author.roles):
        if not message.attachments:
                                      <------------ Some if that detects that theres no text in message
          await message.delete()
      await bot.process_commands(message)
bot.run('-mytokenhere-')
```

i tried
if len(message.content) <0
but users with no roles could still send message with attachments AND text and i dont want that